# facebook app get authentication inside a facebook page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-apps

I have a facebook page 
I have built an application to be in the page tab
the application works fine with the original url 
it get the login from the facebook and return to the url

how i can get the authintication from the user without changing the url "inside the iframe" ?

```
require_once("facebook.php");
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId' => 'App_id',
        'secret' => 'Secret'));
$current_user = $facebook->getUser();

$params = array('scope' =>'email,user_likes,user_friends');
if ($current_user) { 
    try {
            $expiration = time() + 172800; 
            $cookie_value = $current_user . '|' . $expiration;
            setcookie('fbid', $cookie_value, $expiration , "/");
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">
            window.location = "like.php";
            </script>';
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
        window.location = "' . $login_url . '";
        </script>';
        exit;
        error_log($e->getType());
        error_log($e->getMessage());
    }
} else {
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
        window.location = "'.$login_url.'";
        </script>';
    exit;
}
```

Comment: If you want to call the login dialog via URL from within a page tab app, then you have to do that in the top window instance – `top.location.href = 'login-url';` But a much more convenient way to handle login in page tab/canvas apps is to embed the JS SDK, and use it’s `FB.login` method. That does not need to redirect to a different URL, but shows the login dialog in a simple overlay – much nicer user experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a facebook tab application not web application 
and use `JS SDK`